# Combine QUnit's assert.deepEqual() and assert.close()

Tags: javascript, qunit

I have multidimensional arrays of numbers that I want to compare in unit tests, to within some tolerance.

QUnit has `assert.deepEqual()` which would be ideal if it wasn't for float calculation errors that creep in. And the `assert.close` plugin only handles individual numbers.

How might I combine the two? I know custom assertions can be written, so I could make a `assert.deepClose()` assertion which goes through elements using `assert.close()`. But it feels like it would be an awkward duplication of code in `assert.deepEqual()`, unnecessary work and most likely not identical behaviour as might be expected, if that makes sense.

The [source for `assert.deepEqual ()` is here](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/src/assert.js). It seems to use an `equiv ()` function but I'm well out of my depth working out how to modify it with the behaviour of `assert.close ()`.

Is this a common problem in QUnit? How should this be implemented?

Comment: Hmm... based on what you say above, I think a custom assertion is what you will need.